# Save from structure variable

Tags: matlab, save

If I have a structure variable 1x1 with a name of `Data` that contains three fields `voltage`, `data` and `time`, V1, V2 and T. How do I save the voltage data field to separated .txt format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
save('volt_field.mat', '-struct', 'Data', 'V1', 'V2')
save('time_field.mat', '-struct', 'Data', 'T')
```

Comment: save('volt_field.txt', '-struct', 'Data', 'V1', '-ASCII')